# Getting Streaming window timestamp for spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, zeromq, spark-streaming

I am using Spark-streaming to receive data from a zero MQ Queue at an specific interval , enrich it and save it as parquet files .  I want to compare data from one streaming window to another.(later in time using parquet files)

How can I find the timestamps a specific streaming window , which I can  add as another filed while enrichment to facilitate my comparisons.

```
JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(duration));
inputStream = javaStreamingContext.receiverStream(new StreamReceiver( hostName, port, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER()));
JavaDStream<myPojoFormat> enrichedData = inputStream.map(new Enricher());
```

In a nutshell I want time stamp of each streaming window .( Not record level but batch level)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `transform` method of `JavaDStream` which gets a `Function2` s parameter. The `Function2` gets a `RDD` and a `Time` object and returns a new RDD. The overall result will be a new `JavaDStream` in which `RDD` have been trasformed accord the logic you have chosen.

Comment: Mark ,Thanks for the prompt Response. I am already doing a map on inputdata , I want to add the "batch time stamp" on each row of my data, 

I am afraid, I dont think it is possible through transform as i need to add at row level. Please feel free to correct me if i am wrong

Comment: of course you can add the timestamp to each row via the transform method. Inside transform you will have for instance a rdd.map method in which at each line of each rdd you add the timestamp.. you have one timestamp per rdd, which is the timestamp of creation of that rdd...

Comment: Thanks , I figured that out too (but late ), 
I moved my map inside the transform that u suggested , seems to work well